# Quiero validar focus out en un QtableWidgetItem en PyQt 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy ocupando una `QtableWidget` con `PyQt 5` y quisiera saber si hay un método que me permita validar cuando dejó de editar un `QtableWidgetItem`.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Que quieres validar?

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario manejar esos eventos para validar un datos, lo que puedes hacer es usar un delegado como muestro a continuación(esta respuesta la publique en para una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517925/validate-qtablewidget) el sitio en inglés para que solo permite escribir 2 digitos hexadecimales, si tu me dices que quieres validar podria darte una respuesta adecuada para tu pregunta en concreto)

```
class HexDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        w = QLineEdit(parent)
        w.setInputMask("HH")
        return w

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

       # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(HexDelegate())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Mi amiga lo puso eres todo un bilingüe!! y de parte de todo nuestro equipo te agradecemos :D

Comment: @mxmghost Si mi respuesta te ayudo no olvides de marcarla como correcta por favor, si no sabes como hacerlo revisa el siguiente enlace: [tour]